# What is the standard notice period needed to modify the agenda of an AGM?

Tags: management, meetings

My company is holding an annual general meeting (AGM) for its members.  Is there a standard notice period required for a member to put a matter onto the AGM?  We have a member requesting that an item be added to the AGM and are wondering whether too little notice has been given; if it has, then their issue will have to be discussed under Any Other Business.

Comment: There is no standard, any company can use whatever notice period they want/need

Comment: @sf02 possibly "whatever notice period they want/need in accordance with local laws" anyway.

Comment: For people who aren't current on their TLAs, can you please define what an AGM is?

Comment: It could even be location dependent. What country is the company in?

Comment: there you are :)  [AGM](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/annual-general-meeting)

Comment: @alroc Annual General Meeting is what I believe OP is referring to

Answer (score 1):

What's **standard** will depend heavily on the size of the company, whether it's publicly listed or not, and whether the AGM is used to make binding decisions eg via shareholder votes.

If you're trying to come up with a policy, then I'd suggest looking at your competitors/other similar companies and seeing what they do.